If $Z_t \overset{p}{\to} \zeta<\alpha$ and $Z_t<\alpha$ at time $t=T$, will $Z_t$ always remain under $\alpha$ with probability bounded away from 0?
Let $\{Z_t\}_{t=0}^\infty$ be some stochastic process such that $Z_t \overset{p}{\to} \zeta$, where $\zeta\in \mathbb{R}$ is some deterministic, known constant. Fix some (deterministic, known) constants $\alpha>\zeta$  and $\beta<\alpha$.
I want to show that $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall T\in \{0,1,2,...\}$, $\text{Prob}\{Z_t<\alpha \ \forall t\geq T |Z_T\leq \beta\}>\delta$.
My questions Is what I am trying to prove true if one only assumes $Z_t \overset{p}{\to} \zeta$? What if I assumed $Z_t \overset{a.s.}{\to} \zeta$?
My hunch is that the answer is more likely to be "yes" under the $``\overset{a.s.}{\to}\,"$ assumption, but it may also be "yes" under the weaker $``\overset{p}{\to}\,"$ assumption.
I am not entirely sure how to proceed with the proof under either assumption; guidance on how to proceed given each assumption would be very much appreciated.
Edit: The following may possibly be helpful. I have been trying Proof by Contradiction. That is, supposing the negation of what I am trying to prove: suppose that $ \forall \delta>0$, $\exists T_\delta\in\{0,1,2,...\}$ such that $\text{Prob}\{Z_t\geq \alpha \text{ for some }t\geq T|Z_t\leq \beta\}>1-\delta$. That is: given that $Z_T\leq \beta <\alpha$, $\{Z_t\}_{T}^\infty$ will eventually exceed $\alpha$ with probability arbitrarily close to 1. If one assumes $Z_t\overset{a.s.}{\to}\zeta<\alpha$, I would be shocked if no contradiction is reached. I also suspect a contradiction may be possible assuming $Z_t\overset{p}{\to}\zeta<\alpha$. However, in either case, I am having trouble formally getting a contradiction.

No it's not true. $f(x)=x^{-1}\sin x+\alpha$.

Hi Andrew. Did you mean $f(x)=x^{-1}\sin x + \zeta$, where $\zeta<\alpha$? Thanks for taking the time to consider my questions.

Yeah you are right, so my comment does not apply.

I see! Thank you in any case, Andrew.
